# How to pass value from controller to view

Tags: kohana-3

i want to pass a variable to view file. i am using the following code:

```
View::factory('admin/modules/video_category')->set($x, $parent_id);
```

to pass value of $parent_id to $x but $x variable is showing null.
please advise how to do this correctly.

Answer (score 2):

```
View::factory('some_view')->set('variable_name', $value);
```

and than in the view, you can call `$variable_name`.